# compose BlendMode Compatibility issues

Tags: android-jetpack

I want a Black and white mode

```
Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background,) {
     
    MainPage()//Text Image
 
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
        drawRect(
            color = Color.White,
            blendMode = BlendMode.Saturation
        )
    }
}
```

but BlendMode Added in API level 29    [BlendMode](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/BlendMode?hl=en)

what about 28- ？  my test phone is API  26  android 8.0 , white screen

in android View

```
mGrayMatrix.setSaturation(0f)
mGrayPaint.colorFilter = ColorMatrixColorFilter(mGrayMatrix)
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, mGrayPaint)
```

all view change

CompositionLocalProvider、Brush   is too tedious

i need help

in details

Comment: ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541). Can you pleaes ask an actual question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.